# SQL Server working with decimal part of a string in calculations

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion

If I have two columns, A and B, of data type nvarchar(50), where both represent monetary values WITH the currency code (eg. 100.00 USD), how can I use only the decimal part in trigger or procedure calculations?

For example,  an After Insert trigger that subtracts the value of B from A, where A = '300.00 USD' and B = '299.50 USD':

> ...
> AS
>
> declare @a nvarchar(50);
>
> declare @b nvarchar(50);
>
> declare @ans decimal(10,2);
>
> select @a=i.A from inserted i;
>
> select @b=i.B from inserted i;
>
> BEGIN
>
> > *Now I want to find @ans = @a - @b.*
>
> END

What complicates it is that part of the real scenario is doing it in a procedure that tests for a range of values, where I join different tables and output with a "select . . . into".

Comment: Why not store the currency in a separate column

Comment: Just *don't* use a text field for decimal data. The problem is the query, not SQL Server. How do you expect to perform mathematical operations with *text* ? Don't perform operations where currencies are involved either. What's the point of subtracting *pounds* from *dollars* ?

Comment: That would be ideal. Unfortunately, this is for a university project and normalization must be adhered to. The specific table is for booking, and I'm trying to calculate a total price. Third normal form doesn't allow a nonprime attribute to depend on another nonprime attribute, which would be the case if I store currency in a separate column.

Comment: @Nazgul then you failed the project. You *DENORMALIZED* the table, using one text fields where 2 were required. That fails 1NF. You have to *separate* the fields before you can even talk about 3NF.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The subtraction here is just an example. I use currency conversion where needed. The point of the currency code is that payments can be made in different currencies and must thus be stored.

Comment: @Nazgul OK. I suggest you check the meaning of normalization though. You *will* fail if you submit a design that breaks even the first normal form. Yes, store the currencies. Just *don't* mix them up with the amount

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I understand what you're saying, and that's how I initially had it for 1NF...until I reached 3NF.

Comment: @Nazgul you can't have 3NF unless you are already in 2NF. You can't have 2NF unless you are in 1NF. If you think that 3NF requires combining fields, you don't understand it. Higher normalization nubmers result in *more* fields, not less

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks, I'll give normalization a deeper study. I assumed that storing the price+currency as a single attribute was acceptable, but I see what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the currency is exactly three characters, you can lop off the last 4;

```
select cast(left(val, len(val) - 4) as decimal(10, 2))
```

Or, you can use the first space:

```
select cast(left(val, charindex(' ', val)) as decimal(10, 2))
```

I should add that the more typical method of storing currency values is using two columns, one as "money" or "decimal" and the other a currency code.  The only time I would encourage storing monetary values as strings is in databases that do not support fixed-point decimal fields.

You can get the currency code using `right()`.

Comment: Thanks! I agree with having separate columns, but 3NF must be adhered to in my case, and a currency code won't depend on the table's PK.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Convert` & `Replace` functions as next Code:-

```
declare @a nvarchar(50);

declare @b nvarchar(50);

declare @ans decimal(10,2);

set @a = '300.00 USD'
set  @B = '299.50 USD'

set  @ans = convert(decimal(10,2),replace(@a,'USD','')) -
            convert(decimal(10,2),replace(@b,'USD',''))

select @ans
```

**Result:-**

```
0.50
```

Comment: `'1000 USD' - '500 GBP'`. Truncation may allow the statement to execute but the results will be wrong

Comment: Yeah I'd use currency conversion, as stated elsewhere. This was just a very simple example.